# Why does PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher which i applied to an EditText not format made of concurrent 1's

Tags: android

I am using PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher on my editText fields I noticed that it does not format numbers which start with 11, but treats them as normal string. Why is this. And is there a work around to curb the issue ?

This is the XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="8">
            <!-- INPUT -->
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etMobile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_size_8"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp_size_8"
                android:background="@null"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/edt_mobile"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:maxLength="14"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp_size_2" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

This is the usage in  the java activity:

```
etMobile.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());
```

The current local is

> US

Expected number format is

> 1 222-222-2222
>
> 1 333-333-3333

But when a "1" follows after the initial "1", I get

> 11111111111111

Comment: show XML code of EditText

Comment: Please show the code, input text, current output text, expected output text, which version of android you run on, which language/locale is set in the system. Please update your question and answer *all* of the questions so we can figure out what's happening.

Comment: @EugenPechanec done

Comment: @PankajKumar done

Answer (score 1):

It might be that numbers starting with 11 are not a recognized phone number for your given locale to PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher. In my case it was any number starting with 7, 6 or 2.

If you want a work around you can always make your own text watcher or make use of format number function of PhoneNumberUtils.

Comment: I am actually working on production code, so i am not to used to PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.  But how is the locale set ?

Comment: You can set it by new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher(locale) on above LOLLIPOP devices where local is the ISO 3166-1 two-letter country code like "CA"